# How can I solve Error - errorMissingColumn?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, syntax-error

In my select statement I want to `rename column name` which gets data from Postgresql tables.

I have used `AS` to rename column name as below

```
      const data = await this._conn.query(`
            (Select ${this._schema}."names"."table_names" AS "tableNames"
```

However I am getting below error

```
 original: error: column "tableNames" does not exist
      at Connection.parseE (C:\Users\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:614:13)
      at Connection.parseMessage (C:\Users\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:413:19)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\medit\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:129:22)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
    length: 234,
    severity: 'ERROR',
    code: '42703',
    detail: undefined,
    hint: 'Perhaps you meant to reference the column "names.table_names".',
    position: '60',
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: undefined,
    table: undefined,
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: undefined,
    file: 'd:\\pginstaller.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\parser\\parse_relation.c',
    line: '3294',
    routine: 'errorMissingColumn',
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is associated with those two lines? It is it not associated with some code that comes after that actually tries to use the name? If that is the case, posting the full code would be useful.

Comment: I think so, if you look at the `hint` in the above log it clearly targets `select statement`. Okay I will add more code

Comment: Using AS in a query  **does not** rename the column, it creates an alias for the column. However, that alias is only valid for that query and viewing the results of it. But when the query ends so too does the alias. If you want to remame the column you need "[alter table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-altertable.html) rename column ...".